# The best way to secure utility sink legs to concrete floor

Tags: cement

I have a utility sink with metal legs which was never anchored when installed and would like to anchor it to the cement floor. Don't want to go to the expense of using Tapcon screws. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What's your budget if not $6?

Comment: A box of 8 tapcons is $2.75, another option is a box of plastic anchors which will be minimally less. My sink legs are not anchored to the floor but my sink is anchored to the wall. Less work to anchor the sink to the studs than to drill into the concrete.

Comment: Maybe not having a proper drill is part of the expense of the otherwise cheap tapcon?  But if you don't have a drill, you're limited to... adhesive, I guess?

Comment: You can use masonry nails without a drill. It risks chipping the floor and makes removing the sink overly difficult though.

Comment: Masonry nails are not going to do well unless the concrete is fairly new. It takes a big blow with a big hammer to drive them into aged concrete, and an unacceptable level of damage is likely.

Comment: I fully agree with isherwood , using a power driver is another way to do this but with aged concrete you make a big crater I believe the best method to anchor anything in aged concrete is to drill and use red head type anchors , split lead anchors or tapcons for a "rock solid" anchor method, silicone or other epoxy methods maybe I would not use but they may work for a while.

Comment: Most sinks are not secured to the floor, they are secured to the wall.    If your sink is near a wall, attach it to the wall (stud).  You can use nails and leftover wood for this, no need for anything fancy.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "best" is opinion based, and, after 3 years, the OP seems to have abandoned this question.

Comment: Why do you think you need to anchor it?   Most laundry room utility sinks I've seen just sit there.

Answer (score 1):

Get good light to the area.  Make sure floor is very clean and dry.  Buy one tube of 100% clear silicone caulk with gun. Lift each leg individually, stick the tip of the calk tube under the foot and dispense a liberal dose of the calk product directly between the foot and the floor. Let foot rest in puddle.  Repeat for all four legs.  Do not disturb for 24-hours.

Comment: Not a bad option, but the foot on those sinks is small enough, and silicone is soft enough, that a few accidental kicks of the leg is likely to break them loose. I'd probably use construction adhesive.