How can I secure the legs of a utility sink when installing vinyl plank flooring?
I'd like to install vinyl planks in my storage/laundry room. Right now my concern is this   utility sink. I've been told I need to secure the sink so it doesn't move, but I believe drilling through vinyl planks voids the warranty.
Can I put vinyl plank under utility sink? If so how do I secure the sink (drill/screws, glue, something else)
Or should I plank around it some way? I saw one post suggesting making a platform for the sink, which can be secured, and then plank around that.

Related Question:

Safe to install vinyl plank under appliances


secure the sink to the wall

Who told you the sink needed to be secured, and that simply anchoring it to the wall (as opposed to the floor) is insufficient?

@Huesmann home inspector, they didn't say say how it should be attached just that it should and he showed that the feet moved. I guess I jumped to the conclusion that it should be secured with the feet

I think: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/129311/39705 hinted at securing via legs

Shrug.  I had a similar laundry sink in my old house and the legs were definitely not anchored to the floor.  The "bucket" was definitely anchored to the wall though.

The fear of weight on LVP flooring is misunderstood.
Lay your LVP re-install the sink and anchor it to the wall.  ( There is usually slots underneath where the screw anchors can go.) You do not anchor the legs.
Remember LVP is used in homes all over and furniture like sofas, recliners, dining tables and other large pieces are placed on the flooring with no issues. Just follow the instructions and leave the required gap at the wall. (usually 1/4 inch)
